# Alternative to background-position used for loading skeleton ui?

Tags: html, css

Google lighthouse is saying "Unsupported CSS Properties: background-position-x, background-position-y"

I currently have a skeleton-ui that's being used when images or certain things are loading.

According to the docs https://web.dev/animations-guide/ it says to use transform but so far I am not able to get it to animate the same way.

This is the current CSS I have

```
.sc-skeleton {
  background-color: $gray-ten;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, $gray-ten, $gray-eight, $gray-ten);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  animation: sc-skeleton-loading 1.8s ease-in-out 5;
}

@keyframes sc-skeleton-loading {
  0% {
    background-position: -200px 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: calc(200px + 100%) 0;
  }
}
```

[image: Skeleton animation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to use transform to have the exact same results with

```
.sc-skeleton {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: $gray-ten;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.sc-skeleton::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, $gray-ten, $gray-eight, $gray-ten);
  animation: sc-skeleton-loading 1.8s ease-in-out 5;
  content: "";
}
@keyframes sc-skeleton-loading {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a property.  You have to use a keyword value for **background-position**

> /* Keyword values */
> background-position: top;
> background-position: bottom;
> background-position: left;
> background-position: right;
> background-position: center;
>
> /*  values */
> background-position: 25% 75%;
>
> /*  values */
> background-position: 0 0;
> background-position: 1cm 2cm;
> background-position: 10ch 8em;
>
> /* Multiple images */
> background-position: 0 0, center;
>
> /* Edge offsets values */
> background-position: bottom 10px right 20px;
> background-position: right 3em bottom 10px;
> background-position: bottom 10px right;
> background-position: top right 10px;
>
> /* Global values */
> background-position: inherit;
> background-position: initial;
> background-position: revert;
> background-position: revert-layer;
> background-position: unset;

From [Mozilla : background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)